# 'QGIS Processing Executor'_Issue: "sqlite3_open ... unable to open database file"

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, geopackage, standalone

Trying to run a self built-in QGIS-model (*.model3) using the followoing 'QGIS Processing Executor' (`qgis_process`) command in the command line does not work.

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.24.1\apps\Qt5\bin>qgis_process run model:Model
--distance_units=meters --area_units=m2 --ellipsoid=EPSG:7019 --native:buffer_1:result='C:/zz_QGIS_Test_SHPs/result.shp'
```

The above written `QGIS Processing Executor` command is based by following the steps as described in the following picture (see also this [link](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/200))

[image: this attached graphic-1]

By doing so, the further issue appears:

> "...ERROR 4: sqlite3_open('C:/zz_QGIS_Test_SHPs/result.shp'.gpkg)
> failed: unable to open database file..."

[image: this attached graphic-2]

Interesting is though, when the same `QGIS Processing Executor` command is executed with a "temporary layer" (=> `"TEMPORARY_OUTPUT"` instead of a file i.e.: `"result.shp"`) the `qgis_process` command seems to run fine:

[image: this attached graphic-3]

However, I have no idea where the temporary layer is then stored in my PC.

How can I solve the mentioned issue and where are this type of temporary layers stored in the PC?

`QGIS Processing Executor` is an included QGIS-tool which allows to run Processing algorithms and models (built-in or provided by plugins) directly from the command line without starting QGIS Desktop itself.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this: `ERROR 4: sqlite3_open('C:/zz_QGIS_Test_SHPs/result.shp'.gpkg) failed: unable to open database file`, IMHO, there are two things wrong:

- Why is there an attempt to "open" a shapefile as a sql database? **A shapefile is not a sqlite database.** Looks like the geoprocessing tool expects a geopackage.
- `'C:/zz_QGIS_Test_SHPs/result.shp'.gpkg`: I am not sure if this is just the error message from the sqlite Python package, but it looks very much like it is an invalid string

Try to use a geopackage (which is basically an sqlite database with the file extension `gpkg`) instead of a shapefile.